# ¿ Método para calcular los días de un año especifico en JavaScript ? Parecido a mktime() de php

Tags: javascript

¿ Alguien conoce algún método o librería que me permita ingresar una fecha especifica desde la cual iterar y obtener un resultado ?

No sé si me explico. Les muestro lo que necesito hacer a ver si hay algo ya desarrollado:

Necesito hacer esta URL dinámica:

```
http://tapas.clarin.com/tapa/1990/02/22/19900222_thumb.jpg
```

para que me busque las tapas de los diarios Clarín por ejemplo en todo un año especifico.

Por ejemplo desde el 01 del 01 de 1946 hasta el 01/01/1947 !!

Bien, lo que no sé y tampoco quiero calcular es si Febrero del 47 fue bisiesto o no por ejemplo, y estoy buscando alguna librería que ya lo haya calculado así no tengo problemas con las fechas.

¿Alguien conoce algo parecido o alguna idea de como implementar esto ?

Muchas gracias !

Comment: Seguramente tu mejor opción sea https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Voy a chequear, gracias :D